# Two iPads talking to each other

Tags: bluetooth, ipad, wifi

I'm hoping this is a no brainer.  I've been doing iPhone development and have been asked to develop an iPad app for internal company use whereby 2 or 3 iPads in close proximity can talk to each other.

The following description isn't really necessary but I just want to solidify what I mean by "talk to"

Conceptually: three people, each with an iPad, each iPad having the complete listing of e.g., both all UPS packages that arrived/will arrive in the morning delivery totaling 500+ per delivery and an internal hot list of packages that when they arrive must be immediately delivered.  Each of the three people continually grab packages, and select their package from the UPS list.  Other stuff is entered like who gets the package, which internal bin the package was placed, whether on the hot list, etc. but the key is that all information has to be current in real time (+/- a few seconds) on all iPads participating in the package grab.

With the features that the iPad has, what's the best way to make this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the gamekit apis will be ideal

Comment: That's an idea worth looking into!

Comment: Based on our needs, this will work well.  Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write an app that uses Zeroconf/Bonjour to discover other instances of the app running and send XMPP messages around.

Comment: Thanks.  Presumably with this solution the iPads have to be on a network already rather than just talking to each other independent of any other hardware (which I'm not sure is possible).  This would be potentially limiting if the grabbers are in the metal trucks in the parking lot possibly out of range of wi-fi router.  Could this work with a 3G connection?  I guess the ideal solution would be the iPads talking to each other without the need for any other hardware and the next best solution would be one using a 3G connection.

Comment: With a 3G connection you'd probably have to have them connecting to a central server instead of them finding each other.